# Please help, I have been attempting to understand Quicksort for 9 hours now with little luck!

Tags: algorithms, quicksort, java

I have done absolutely everything that i could to try to understand this algorithm. I did NOT want to go on without understanding it completely even though I know it might only be a single problem in the midterm and I think I might have already burned myself out anyways. I even performed the algorithm by hand, which did allow me to understand that when the high_border and low_border indices are equal, to only swap it with the pivot if arr[low_border] is greater than the pivot. This helped when I was trying to sort the following array: {3, 4, 1, 7, 5, 8, 0}. But even then, the computer only sometimes sorts it correctly. The same can be said for any other list. Here is the video that I tried to follow when learning about this algorithm:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fiot5yuwPAg&t=59s

Please help me, I have been at this for 9 total hours (3 last night, 3 before I went to class and another 3 right after class).

The full code for the program(in java) is here:
https://pastebin.com/cRF1xjcs

Comment: A suggestion for you. Have a piece of paper, a pencil. Randomly pick 10 or more un-sorted numbers. Follow the algorithm, see if you can manually sort the numbers before you jump to the code.

Comment: This seems more like a debugging question than a computer science question. Are you confused about the algorithm in general, or why your code isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

Elements that are equal to the pivot are not getting moved correctly. You need to change one of your checks (> or <, pick one; usual choice is to use >=) to include the equal case in `partition`. Also, your `else if (high_border == low_border)` can just be `else`, since that is your only option by your `while` loop break condition. In that case, you do not always swap `end` with something in the middle so that the pivot remains at the end of the array after every element larger than it in some cases. Switching the `>` to `>=` as I mentioned may fix that, but I would put an `else` case to swap the pivot with `high_border` just in case. Then you would also need to return `high_border`. I don't see any other problems with your code, but those couple of fixes are majorly important.

Comment: Sorry for responding very late, but which checks are you referring  to?

Comment: I mean just testing less than or greater than causes issues when elements compare equal. Use `>=` instead of `>`.